# Equivalent of sencha touch on HTML 5 but on Flash?

Tags: flash, html

Does something exist which is equivalent of sench touch but on pure flash to create tabs and forms

Answer (score 0):

FlexBuilder aka FlashBuilder is Adobe's product for doing this. (But you end up with a file that requires the Adobe runtime interpreter --  not with HTML + javascript). It would be cool if the output of FlashBuilder could be HTML5 + javascript.